# Want to capture all frames when a face is present in frame

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera, video-streaming

I am trying to build a dataset of face images, I have searched and find a code that is working fine with my laptop's webcam but when I am trying to capture with IP Camera which is usually used for surveillance than code is not working.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

count = 0
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
        count = count + 1
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Another thing I want to mention my laptop Camera resolution is 640.0 480.0 and IP Cameras have 2560.0 1440.0. Please help me to capture all frames when face is present.

Comment: You should include a conditional statement before `cv2.imwrite`. Check whether `faces` is `True` using `if` condition and save the frame.

Comment: @JeruLuke This code is working and giving frames properly on webcam where resolution is low but when I am running this code for another Camera which have higher resolution than the solution is not working.

Comment: Please explain `"not working"`. Is it throwing an error? If so what's the error message? If the output is not what you expected show it. If there is any other issue please explain/show in detail

Comment: @JeruLuke not working means not capturing the images not storing any image when running on IP Camera

Comment: @Muhammad Awais Amin "You mentioned High resolution camera". It is USB 2 or 3?

Comment: If you're using this detectMultiScale. That means you have to detect the rectangle.. Without detectMultiScale will work

Comment: @toyotaSupra it is available on network. link is like following 
'rtsp://admin:admin@192.1.1.24/H264?ch=2&subtype=0'

Comment: Is your laptop comes with hdmi? Is comes with build-in camera?

Comment: @toyotaSupra with build-in camera it is working well. but when I am running this on camera which is on network it is not capturing images.

Comment: @toyotaSupra my laptop have HDMI and it also have build-in Camera. Code is working fine with build-in camera. It creating the problem with IP Cmera

Comment: What is your rtsp format?

Comment: I understood. You cannot save without using  rtsp or pipeline, etc

Comment: @toyotaSupra you got the my point or not? Are you able to help to solve this issue?

Comment: I cannot help[ you. Do google search  rtsp opencv python

Comment: @toyotaSupra what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved after adjusting the resolution, I have added the line of code for frame adjustment `frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1360, 768))` than code has started working properly.

This code might be helpful for anyone.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.1.1.24/H264?ch=2&subtype=0/1')

count = 0
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1360, 768))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
        count = count + 1
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture images from specific camera you need to change arguments in `cv2.VideoCapture(argument)`. For example:

- `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`: it's used to select the default camera, generally laptop inbuilt camera.
- `cv2.VideoCapture(n)` `where n>=1`: it's used to select the other external camera connect to laptop through usb/other ports
- `cv2.VideoCapture('protocol://IP:port/1')`: it's used to take input from network cameras(like in your case)
- Here `protocol` means: HTTP/RTSP etc.
- `IP` means hosting address: Example: 192.168.18.37
- `port` where the IP address is accessed

In this case it should be:

```
cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.1.1.24/H264?ch=2&subtype=0/1')
```

Comment: I know how to edit code for IP Camera.
When I am running with IP Camera using `cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.1.1.24/H264?ch=2&subtype=0/1')` code is not storing any image however same code is working and capturing the images when I am using `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. 
I have to figure out this problem.

Comment: `ret,frame = cap.read()` while executing this whats the value of `ret`?

Comment: One more thing please make sure you have used `/1` at the end of `cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.1.1.24/H264?ch=2&subtype=0/1)`

Comment: `ret` is returning `True`

Comment: what's the output of `frame.shape`?

Comment: The output of `frame.shape` is `(1440, 2560, 3)`

Comment: What does `faces` return? @MuhammadAwaisAmin

Comment: Where the faces are detected using built-in camera `frame.shape` returns `(480, 640, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the resolution before image capture is more optimal. There would be no need to resize every subsequent frame.

Before the `while` loop set the width and height as follows:

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 768)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1380)
```

[Different flags used for video streaming](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704dab26d2ba37086662261148e9fe93eecad)

Comment: This solution I tried but not working in my case. I don't know why.

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisAmin What is your `frame` shape when using this? And is `ret` `True`?